# How to update bridgeOS without internet connection?

Tags: software-update, firmware, t2

We recently tried to update an air gapped Mac Mini 2018 with the [10.14.6 Combo Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2010?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). It failed because the bridgeOS version was too old. On an internet connected Mac it just downloads the latest version of bridgeOS and completes the update, but I haven't found a way to download and install it manually from a USB drive.

Well, I've found [one way](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/apple-configurator-2/apdebea5be51/mac), which seems quite cumbersome and unnecessary. Also, it's clearly designed for fixing broken firmware and not for routine updates. Does anyone know if there is a better way?

Comment: Will this help: https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-restore-bridgeos-on-a-t2-mac-how-to-put-a-mac-into-dfu-mode/

Comment: @Udhy Thanks, but that's the same method I linked in the question.